# How do I read midi / musicxml files in music21 for solo piano where there can be multiple notes in a voice simultaneously?

Tags: python, parsing, midi, music21, musicxml

I have written a python script to process midi files with music21 and write again a midi file. This works if the solo piano is "simple" in the sense, that there are not multiple pitches / notes played simultaneously in a voice.

https://github.com/githubuser1983/algorithmic_python_music/blob/main/12RootOf2.py

The relevant part from above is:

```
def parseMidi(fp,part=0):
    import os
    from music21 import converter
    print(fp)
    score = converter.parse(fp,quantizePost=True)
    print(list(score.elements[0].notesAndRests))
    #print([e.partAbbreviation for e in score.elements][0])
    from music21 import chord
    durs = []
    ll0 = []
    vols = []
    isPauses = []
    for p in score.elements[part].notesAndRests:
        #print(p)
        if type(p)==chord.Chord:
            pitches = median([e.pitch.midi-21 for e in p]) # todo: think about chords
            vol = median([e.volume.velocity for e in p])
            dur = float(p.duration.quarterLength)
            #print(pitches)
            ll0.append(pitches)
            isPause = False
        elif (p.name=="rest"):
            pitches = 89
            vol = 1
            dur = float(p.duration.quarterLength)
            ll0.append(pitches)
            isPause = True
        else:
            pitches = p.pitch.midi-21
            vol = p.volume.velocity
            dur = float(p.duration.quarterLength)
            ll0.append(pitches)
            isPause =  False
        durs.append(dur/(12*4.0))
        vols.append(vol*1.0/127.0)
        isPauses.append(isPause)
            #print(p.name,p.octave,p.duration.quarterLength)
    #print(dir(score)) 
    #print(ll0)
    #print(durs)
    return ll0,durs,vols,isPauses
```

Another option would be to to read musicxml instead of midi. What I need for the algorithm to work, is a list of note(s) = (pitch, duration, volume, isPause) for each voice.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Music21 works with MIDI, but excels with musicxml -- in addition to the answers and comments below, consider changing your files to musicxml as quickly as possible.  Musescore does a great job of batch converting MIDI to musicxml.

Comment: @michaelscottcuthbert how would i do that in musicxml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, in music21, `stream.Voice` objects are more of a display concept than a logical concept. Voices and Chords are both simultaneities, and that's all that a MIDI file captures. (In fact, there are [pending changes](https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21/pull/812) in version 7, to be released this week, that make fewer voices and more chords from MIDI files, in addition to making measures. If there are small overlaps from reverb or from a recorded performance you may get "voices" that an engraver would never print in sheet music.)

In your case, I would probably just take a `.flat` of the `Part` object to get rid of Voices (and eventually Measures in v.7), and then run `chordify()` if you want to ensure there are no overlaps. Otherwise, if you don't want chords at all, you can still take the output of chordify() and find the root of each chord. Several possibilities that all depend on what your sources look like.

Comment: What Jacob said -- either (a) run chordify() before your per-voice script.  Or replace `score.elements[part].notesAndRests` with `score.elements[part].recurse().notesAndRests`  -- thanks for using music21!